# Слово "кромешный"

Tags: фразеология

Часто в поговорках употребляется слово "кромешный": "кромешный ад", "кромешная тьма". Что означает это слово?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Старославянское слово "кромешный" происходит от слова "край". Раньше считалось, что Солнце освещает только определенный "небесный купол", за пределами которого находится непроглядная тьма. То есть, "кромешный" — означает "находящийся за краем, где всегда темно".